# getchar() function in c

Tags: c, file, scanf, getchar

**I have just started learning I/O file operations in c** from **programming in c** by **stephen Kochan**. In one of the exercise questions like the one below

> Write a program that displays the contents of a file at the terminal 20 lines at a time. At the end of each 20 lines, have the program wait for a character to be entered from the terminal. If the character is the letter q, the program should stop the display of the file; any other character should cause the next 20 lines from the file to be displayed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int count=0,c;
  FILE *fname;
  char name[64];
  char again='a';
  printf("enter the name of file to be read : ");
  scanf("%s",name);
  if((fname=fopen(name,"r"))==NULL){
    printf("file %s cannot be opened for reading \n",name);
    return 1;
  }
  while(again!='q'){
      count=0;
      while((c=getc(fname))!=EOF)
          {
            if(c!='\n')
              {
                putchar(c);
              }
            else{
              putchar('\n');
              count++;
              printf("count = %i\n",count); //debug statement
              }
            if(count>19)
              break;
          }
      again=getchar();
      printf("again = %c\n",again); //debug statement
    }
fclose(fname);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

In the above program, when i looked at the output initially, the program was displaying 40 numbers without taking a break at 20 numbers, so i have included some debugging statements in the above to see where i am going wrong and the output i was getting was:

```
count = 1
2
count = 2
3
count = 3
4
count = 4
5
count = 5
6
count = 6
7
count = 7
8
count = 8
9
count = 9
10
count = 10
11
count = 11
12
count = 12
13
count = 13
14
count = 14
15
count = 15
16
count = 16
17
count = 17
18
count = 18
19
count = 19
20
count = 20
again = //it skipped the loop the first time

21
count = 1
22
count = 2
23
count = 3
24
count = 4
25
count = 5
26
count = 6
27
count = 7
28
count = 8
29
count = 9
30
count = 10
31
count = 11
32
count = 12
33
count = 13
34
count = 14
35
count = 15
36
count = 16
37
count = 17
38
count = 18
39
count = 19
40
count = 20
q
again = **need to input here**
```

So for the first time, the `getchar()` is not prompting for an input. So i replaced the part where `getchar()` is with:

```
scanf(" %c",&again);
```

It's working fine as expected. The program is prompting for an input **for the first time after the 20 new lines**. I also left some whitespace so that `scanf` would ignore it. So long post short, I don't think i had understood the behavior of `getchar()` completely. I am trying to learn these things myself, i Googled for an explanation but i came up empty. Any help and feedback about this would be really appreciated.

Comment: `getchar` returns an **int**, not char, because it has to return EOF, so please change `again` to `int`

Comment: but there were programs in which `getchar()` is used to get the next character from the user?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc i changed it, but it's still behaving the same

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

Once you get to this point in your program and you type the name of the file and press enter, a linefeed character (`\n`) is added to the input stream which is not read by `scanf`, but instead is picked up by the first call to `getchar()` instead.

Another problem with using `scanf` to read in a filename is that it is cumbersome to handle filenames with spaces. Consider using `fgets()` instead, which will both read the linefeed character and handle filenames with spaces. The downside to using `fgets()` is that you have to strip the `\n` character yourself.

```
#include <string.h>

// ... 

char name[64];

if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) != NULL)
{
    // strip the linefeed character off
    size_t len = strlen(name);
    if (len > 0 && name[len - 1] == '\n')
        name[len - 1] = '\0';
}
else
{
    // if fgets returns NULL then an error with the input occurred
}
```

A shorter, but perhaps not as clear way to strip the linefeed character:

```
name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: thanks. that kinda makes sense. not completely though. could you elaborate a bit more?. i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is one that bites most new C programmers who use `scanf` and do not account for *All* characters in the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`). When you call `scanf` using `%s` as the *format-specifier*, type input and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, everything up to the *first whitespace* character is read into the pointer variable specified in the argument list -- *leaving* `'\n'` (which is whitespace) unread in `stdin`. The next time you attempt to read from `stdin`, the trailing `'\n'`from your previous call to `scanf` is the first thing read. If whatever you are reading from `stdin` with doesn't handle the `'\n'` - you have a problem.

To properly handle the issue, either account for the newline in your *format-string* on each call to `scanf`, or loop over `stdin` with `getchar()` until a `'\n'` (or `EOF`) is encountered. Using the format-string, you could use:

```
scanf("%s%*c",name);      /* you should check the return == 1 */
```

or to allow spaces in the string

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",name);  /* ditto */
```

Where `%[^\n]` reads all characters up to, but not including the newline (allowing spaces in the string) and `%*c` reads and discards the `'\n'` without adding to the *match-count* (the `'*'` being the *assignment-suppression* operator) You should also add `%63[^\n]` to limit the number of character read to prevent writing beyond your array bounds.

But if the purpose of the exercise is to familiarize yourself with the *character-oriented-input* functions (`getchar`, `fgetc`, etc..), why use anything other than that to begin with? You could simply do something like:

```
enum { MAXL = 20, MAXC = 256 };
...

    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : NULL;

    if (!fp) {
        char fname[MAXC] = "";
        char *p = fname;
        int n = 0;
        printf ("\nenter a filename: ");
        while (n + 1 < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) *p++ = c, n++;
        *p = 0;
        fp = fopen (fname, "r");
        if (!fp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Putting the remainder together and whittling down the logic a bit, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXL = 20, MAXC = 256 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c, idx = 0, pgsz = MAXL, line = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : NULL;

    if (!fp) {
        char fname[MAXC] = "";
        char *p = fname;
        int n = 0;
        printf ("\nenter a filename: ");
        while (n+1 < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) *p++ = c, n++;
        *p = 0;
        fp = fopen (fname, "r");
        if (!fp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') idx++;
        if (idx == pgsz) {
            line += pgsz;
            printf ("\n__ line %d, quit (q)? ", line);
            int ch;
            if ((ch = getchar()) == 'q') break;
            while ((ch = getchar() != '\n' && ch != EOF)) {}
            idx = 0;
        }
        else
            putchar (c);
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pager

enter a filename: ../dat/100int.txt
27086
29317
...
29927
24511
__ line 20, quit (q)? q
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code. I haven't removed the debugging statements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int count=0,c;
FILE *fname;
char name[64];
char again='a';
printf("enter the name of file to be read : ");
scanf("%s",name);
getchar();
if((fname=fopen(name,"r"))==NULL){
  printf("file %s cannot be opened for reading \n",name);
  return 1;
}
while(again!='q'){
  count=0;
  while((c=getc(fname))!=EOF)
      {
        if(c!='\n')
          {
            putchar(c);
          }
        else{
          putchar('\n');
          count++;
          printf("count = %i\n",count); //debug statement
          }
        if(count>19)
          break;
      }

    again=getchar();
  printf("again = %c\n",again); //debug statement
}
fclose(fname);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

What i did is, added a `getchar()` after `scanf()`. To clear the `ENTER` left by `scanf()` in the buffer.